# Previous session can not destroy in laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel

I am creating login page & after logout my session value can not destroy. Any problem with code? I am using flush method,forget method to remove previous session value.

```
public function userLogin(Request $req)
     {
          $username=$req->input('username');
          $password=$req->input('password');
          $finduser = Users::where(['email'=>$username,'password'=>$password])
                         ->orwhere(['mobile'=>$username,'password'=>$password])
                         ->first();

        Session::put('username', $finduser->name);
        Session::put('userid', $finduser->id);
        $session_id=Session::get('session_id');

        if($username != $finduser->mobile and $username != $finduser->email)
        {
            Session::put('message','Email or mobile number does not exists');
            return redirect::to('/login');
        }
        else if($password !=  $finduser->password)
        {
            Session::put('message','Your Password is incorrect');
            return redirect::to('/login');
        }
        else if($finduser)
        {
            return redirect::to('/home');
        }
}


public function logout(Request $req)
     {
         Session()->forget(['userid', 'username','session_id']);
         Session()->flush();
         //Session::flush();
         return redirect('/login');
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `\Session()->flush();` instead of `Session()->flush();`